# Converting two column of data to proper tabular format

Tags: postgresql, pivot, postgresql-9.1, crosstab

I'm having the data in format given below.

```
Col1  |  Col2
_______________
item1 | orange 
item2 | apple
item1 | guava
item2 | noodles
...
```

I want data to be in below format.

```
item1  |  item2
_______________
orange |  apple
guava  |  noodles
...
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.

Is it possible to do it in single SQL query?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+pivot

Comment: @krishna see this well explained [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/3682599)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)